# Couldn't get UEFI db list and more errors after system cheking in progress on disk `

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi

I have seen some questions on this related error and have tried the correspondent answers, but it has not worked in my case.

I have only ubuntu 18.04 installed in the machine. First, the following error shows up:

```
[   0.790413] Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000e
[   0.790430] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[   0.790786] Couldn't get size: 0x880000000000000e
[   0.791475] Couldn't parse dbx signatures: -74
[   1.231173] ACPI error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUEND (20170831/psargs-364)
[   1.231209] ACPI error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCIO.SATO.SPTO._GTF, AE_NOT FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[   1.232062] ACPI error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
[   1.232096] ACPI error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCIO.SATO.SPTO._GTF, AE_NOT FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
/dev/sda3: clean, 515059/9125888 files, 9894162/36496128 blocks
[8.337492] PKCS#7 signature with a trusted key

You are in emergeny mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, ...

Press Enter for maintenance
```

The OS was working ok, but sometimes asked to fsck manually to fix some errors.

Comment: crickets...  same here after macbook upgrade to 18.04